# Cannot return a cli array of a generic type

Tags: c++-cli

I got this function

```
array<ItemType>^ GetNextItems(int n) {
    auto ret = gcnew Collections::Generic::List < ItemType > ;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        auto item = GetNextItem();
        if (item == ItemType()) break;
        ret->Add(item);
    }
    return ret->ToArray();
}
```

But the compile gives me an error: cannot convert from 'cli::array< ItemType,1 > ^' to 'cli::array< ItemType,1 > ^'

ItemType is a template parameter ie.

```
generic <typename ItemType>
```

I've been staring at this for a while, I can't detect the fault. Why won't it compile?

Comment: This is weird. Have you tried explicitly declaring `ret` as a `List<ItemType>^`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Can you give a more complete code example, perhaps one that includes `GetNextItem()` and the class definition that they're both in?

Answer (score 1):

If `ItemType` is a .NET/CLR type, then you'll need the ^-hat inside the return type declaration.  The `^` is still *not* included in the actual type declaration.

So it would be something like this:

```
generic <typename ItemType>
ref class Test
{
    array<ItemType ^>^
    GetNextItems(int n)
    {
        List<ItemType ^> ^ ret = gcnew List<ItemType ^>(n);
        ...
        return ret->ToArray();
    }
};
```

Notice the added caret inside the `<ItemType ^>` return type declaration, but not in the class' `generic` definition.

Comment: Fixed my problem where I was trying to create a List of Arrays: List<array<int,2>^>^ myList works. I was trying without the inside carret.